# Passing array of a pointer to structure

Tags: c

I'm making a simple program about sorting five teams from 1st to 5th.. but i wanted to make it by using Array of pointers & passing structures methods. here is what i've done..

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


struct league 
{
 char team1[20]; 
 char team2[20]; 
 char team3[20];
 char team4[20];
 char team5[20];
};


char *Arrange(struct league *table)

{
 struct league *Ptable[5] = {0};
  int i;

  Ptable[0]-> team5;
  Ptable[1]-> team2;
  Ptable[2]-> team3;
  Ptable[3]-> team1;
  Ptable[4]-> team4;

 for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)

  printf("%s\n", &Ptable[i]);

return Ptable[i];
}


int main()

{
struct league table;

 strcpy(table.team1,"Arsenal");
 strcpy(table.team2,"Man City");
 strcpy(table.team3,"LiverPool");
 strcpy(table.team4,"Totenham");
 strcpy(table.team5,"Chelsea");

printf("League table:\n");

 Arrange(&table);


return 0;
}
```

when i compile it i get this error:

```
warning: format ‘%s’ expects argument of type ‘char *’, but argument 2 has type ‘struct league **’ [-Wformat=]
   printf("%s\n", &Ptable[i]);
```

what is the right way to code this without making too many changes on my code? because i want to be using array of pointers with structures in a code like this.

Comment: This code doesn't do what you think it does.  `Ptable[i]` is a pointer to a struct league.  Each league struct has 5 members each of which are 20 character arrays.  The five Ptable[i}->teami statements don't do anything.

Comment: Note that it is Tottenham Hotspurs (Spurs) — two t's in the middle.  And Liverpool; no capital in the middle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each team in the league is a string, not a structure, so you don't need an array of structure pointers, just an array of pointers to the strings.

```
char *Arrange(struct league *table) {
    char *Ptable = malloc(5 * sizeof(char *));
    Ptable[0] = table->team5;
    Ptable[1] = table->team2;
    Ptable[2] = table->team3;
    Ptable[3] = table->team1;
    Ptable[4] = table->team4;
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", &Ptable[i]);
    }
    return Ptable;
}
```

To return an array, you need to allocate it dynamically with `malloc()`, then return that pointer.

Comment: thank you.. it worked, i have try it before with just an array of pointers but i  wrote it like this Ptable[0] = team5; etc.. i didn't put table->.. i didn't understand your last sentence about returning Ptable, but i returned Ptable[i] and it worked too.

Comment: @whiteknights After the loop, `i = 5`. There is no `Ptable[i]`, the valid elements are `Ptable[0]` through `Ptable[4]`.

Comment: thank you.. isn't Ptable[0] just one element? and i want to return all of the elements.

Comment: You can't return a local array, you need to allocate it dynamically with `malloc()`. I've updated the answer to show this.